# How to add condition in between fields in Profile2 module in drupal 7?

Tags: 7, users

I am using the [Profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) module.
Two fields are there in the Registration Form i.e.

**I am** : [Baby Male, Baby Female, Daddy, Mummy]

&

**Looking For** : [Baby Male, Baby Female, Daddy, Mummy].

if user click on **I am** : [Baby Male] then in **Looking For**: [Baby Female] is only show.

If select **I am** : [Baby Female] then in  **Looking For**: [Baby Male].

So If **I am** : [Daddy] then in  **Looking For**: [Mummy] & If **I am** : [Mummy] then in  **Looking For**: [Daddy].

How can I do this?. Is there any module in Drupal 7?

Comment: Check once https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields

Comment: I think yes, As suggested by @Smalution, [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module is what you're looking for.Smalution you can add this as an answer :)

Comment: Thanks... through this module we can apply condition between fields but i have a query that through this module can i apply condition between options or between these four options...???

Comment: @samzha you accepted the answer. Then what's your problem? didn't you solve that? How can I help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this also option wise using field conditional state module.

Go through this [field_conditional_state](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_conditional_state) for details.

Trigger a state when applied to a control field:

```
    empty - Triggers when the control field is empty
    filled - Triggers when the control field is not empty
    checked - Triggers when the control field is checked
    unchecked - Triggers when the control field is not checked
    value - Triggers when the control field's value is equal to a given string
    !value - Triggers when the control field's value is NOT equal to a given string
```

Comment: Please help me to do this through field_conditional_state...@Smalution

Comment: @samzha Can you write down the problem you are facing.

Comment: Actually i try to solve this through field_condition_state... but can't understand how can i implement... Please help me, i am using frst time this module...

Comment: First may u pls tell me "field_condition_state" is work with "conditional_field" or work independently...

Comment: it works independently.

Comment: i already try to implement through Conditional Fields... But can add condition in fields only not in option. I want to add condition in options as per question. May u pls help me to solve this through field_conditional_state