# How to create a view displaying a list of users who have logged-in user's preferences

Tags: views

How does one create a view that filters users so as to display those with preferences of the logged-in user (the one viewing them)? I'm using Drupal 7.34, Views 3.

E.g. A user selects a preference on sign up, such as "**i'm interested in a man**". How do you create a view that will show this user a list of users who selected "**I'm a man**" on their own signups. Think of it as matchmaking.

I came across this [discussion](https://groups.drupal.org/node/187034) but didnt figure out [this comment](https://groups.drupal.org/node/187034#comment-1055458). All the articles out there don't seem to address this clearly.

I'm certain there is a contextual filter move I'm missing. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue but solved by using this custom code in view. I was using [profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) module for registration so as per sex field, I was done this :

```
global $user;
$profiles = profile2_load_by_user($user);
foreach ($profiles as $profile) {
  if ($items = field_get_items('profile2', $profile, 'field_seeking')) {
    break;
  }
}
   return $items[0]['value'];
```

Please check my Post **[HERE](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/129997/how-to-add-condition-in-between-fields-in-profile2-module-in-drupal-7)**.

As per my post I was do this :

```
global $user;
    $profiles = profile2_load_by_user($user);
    foreach ($profiles as $profile)
    {
        if ($items = field_get_items('profile2', $profile, 'field_sex'))
      {
            break;
          }
    }

    $i_am=$items[0]['value'];

    if($i_am=='sdmale' || $i_am=='sbmale')
    {

    $looking='smfemale+sbfemale';
    }

    if($i_am=='smfemale' || $i_am=='sbfemale')
    {
    $looking='sdmale+sbmale';
    }
    return $looking;
```

Comment: **Where** in View did you enter this custom code?I'm using core profile, not profile2.

Comment: Enable PHP Filter module & you'll get an option in view & add your code there.

Comment: Despite activating those modules, and adding the code with few adaptations nothing is happening. I'm new at coding php. Should I put only field in "field_get_items" when in reality drupal is supposed to manipulate data from 2 fields and from 2 different users in any single session?